# How do I disable fading animation when changing wallpapers? 

Tags: desktop-background, animations

I'm using 12.04. When I change wallpapers, I don't want to wait for the old wallpaper to fade out and the new one fade in. Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

To disable this fading is to turn off the hole gtk animations. Do this by editing or creating the file `~/.gtkrc-*.0` and add this line:

```
gtk-enable-animations = 0
```

Then log-off and on again.

Note: * refers to your gtk version (2 or 3) so replace it with yours.

Answer (score 0):

In 13.10 Saucy Salamander, the setting is `org.gnome.nautilus.desktop` -> `background-fade`, can be disabled using `dconf-editor` (Hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> to find it). You don't need to log out or restart something.