# How to disable gnome-shell background fade transition?

Tags: gnome, gnome-shell

I have a script that modifies my background `wallpaper.jpg` every now and then. Currently, gnome fades the image out and back in every time my script changes the file. How can I eliminate the fade transition, so that the background changes immediately?

The solutions outlined [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/184070/how-do-i-disable-fading-animation-when-changing-wallpapers#379343) don't work for me on gnome-shell 3.24